# Error while submitting form Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have code in router:

```
/**************Quản lý user*****************/
Route::get('admin/manage-user', 'UserController@getList')->middleware('admin');
Route::get('admin/manage-user/add', 'UserController@indexAdd')->middleware('admin');
Route::post('admin/manage-user/add', 'UserController@getAdd')->middleware('admin');
```

Code in UserController:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests\AddUserRequest;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function getList()
    {
        $data = User::paginate(10);
        return view('admin.manage-user',['data' => $data]);
    }
    public function indexAdd()
    {
        return view('admin.add-user');
    }
    public function getAdd(AddUserRequest $request)
    {
        if($request->fails())
            return view('admin.add-user')->withInput();
    }
}
```

Code in AddUserRequest

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AddUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required|max:200',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'pass1' => 'required|min:6',
            'pass2' => 'required|same:pass1',
        ];
    }
}
```

Code view errors:

```
    @extends('layouts.admin')
@section('title','Add User')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Add User</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
            <form role="form" action="{{url('admin/manage-user/add')}}" method="post">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
```

When running the path: http://localhost/LBlog/public/admin/manage-user/add and submit (Do not enter form information), the screen returns error: The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.
I hope someone can help me with this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error appears due to CSRF token.

Add csrf token in your form.

```
          <form role="form" action="{{url('admin/manage-user/add')}}" method="post">
              @csrf
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
```